# How to make a column fill the offset space

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

i don't know how to ask this properly, but I have this problem:

I have to create 2 views, this is the [mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkpnX.png)

Now, the problem is with the [other view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3M9z.png)

I want that the first column and the last one fill the remain height.

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-2" style="background-color: aqua;">co</div>
    <div class="col-10 col-md-6" style="background-color: yellow;">titulo</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-2" style="background-color: red;">Descr</div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4" style="background-color: rebeccapurple;">Precop</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Everything seems normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the boostrap line is composed of 12 columns. In a medium size screen (col-md) you first column (co) is taking 2 columns and the second one (titulo) is taking 6 columns. So with your first 2 columns you use 8 columns on 12 available for a line. And as you third column (Descr) use 6 columns, it can't fit on the first line because you firsts 3 element are taking more than 12 columns.

So you need to resize your columns; If you want all of them on one line for exemple, you need that the sum of all your columns doest not exceed 12.

Comment: You're right is bootstrap col sistem that I'am not organizing correctly. But the problem is that I don't want all in one line

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood, what is it that you want to do ?
You wanna put precop on the first line to fill remain space ?